# Swiftshader ( Angle Project ) vsync not working, how to solve?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, egl

I used **libglesv2.dll**, **libegl.dll** library from (**Angle** project)..

( Note: that dlls i get from swift shader folder )

default dlls works perfectly with vsync, but **swiftshadder** dlls **vsync not works**..

i enable vsync via **eglSwapInterval**(egl_display, **1**);

without vsync i get tearing..

**My question is**

1, How to achive 60fps 90fps 120fps without tearing..?

2, ( without tearing ) Vsync only solution then, how to works with
swiftshadder..vsync ?

see here sample code.. its works vsync on defualt dlls, but failed with swiftshaddder dlls..

```
EGLConfig egl_config;
EGLint num_config, majorVersion, minorVersion;

EGLint config_attrib_list[] = {
    EGL_BUFFER_SIZE, 16,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,
    EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
    EGL_NONE
};

EGLint context_attrib_list[] = {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
        EGL_NONE
};

egl_display = eglGetDisplay(NULL);
eglInitialize(egl_display, &majorVersion, &minorVersion);
eglChooseConfig(egl_display, config_attrib_list, &egl_config, 1, &num_config);
egl_surface= eglCreateWindowSurface(egl_display, egl_config, (NativeWindowType)hwnd, NULL);
egl_context = eglCreateContext(egl_display, egl_config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, context_attrib_list);
eglMakeCurrent(egl_display, egl_surface, egl_surface, egl_context);
eglSwapInterval(egl_display, 1);

const char *vs = "\
            attribute vec2 pos;\
            uniform vec2 offset;\
            void main() {\
                gl_Position = vec4(pos + offset, 0, 1);\
            }";

GLuint vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vs, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
const char *fs = "\
            void main() {\
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);\
            }";
GLuint fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fs, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
glLinkProgram(program);
glUseProgram(program);
glViewport(0, 0, 1366, 768);

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point b = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

while ()
{
    if (exit_app) break;

    render();

    a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> work_time = a - b;
    if (work_time.count() < 16.44)
    {
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> delta_ms(16.44 - work_time.count());
        auto delta_ms_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(delta_ms);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delta_ms_duration.count()));
    }
    b = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    eglSwapBuffers(egl_display, egl_surface);

}
```

default dlls ( **libglesv2.dll**, **libegl.dll** ) vsync works, i got 60fps.. smoother..
swiftshader dlls ( **libglesv2.dll**, **libegl.dll** ) vsync not works, i got 60fps with tearing..

see here simpile shape render code..

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
static const float vertices[] = {
   1.0f,  0.0f,
  -0.5f,  0.5f,
   0.5f, -0.5f
};
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    2 * sizeof(float), (GLvoid*)vertices
);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GLuint offset_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "offset");
glUniform2f(offset_loc, cosf(frame_number*0.1f), 0);
frame_number++;
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Comment: We need at least an [mcve] to help you.

Comment: I see no mention of the render function or how swiftshader fits into this.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282252/can-eglswapinterval0-cause-screen-tearing) mentions that the swap interval is silently clamped to a value between `EGL_MIN_SWAP_INTERVAL` and `EGL_MAX_SWAP_INTERVAL`. Did you check those?

Comment: Where are you actually seeing the swap interval being honored in the SwiftShader source in any of the [`FrameBuffer*` backends](https://github.com/google/swiftshader/tree/master/src/Main)?